# Logic: How does Distributive work if both the terms also have an And/Or argument?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have $¬(¬(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (¬R ∨ ¬Q)),$ I know I can distribute to get:

$¬((¬P ∨ Q) ∨ (¬R ∨ ¬Q))$ ... my question is a little basic but I don't know whether my next step will be:

$(P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (R ∧ Q)$ or $(P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ (R ∧ Q)$

I'm inclined to believe the second of the two is correct, as my truth table is giving false for everything and the second gives $¬Q ∧ Q$ which will be false.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: You are looking for [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 3):

By *DeMorgan's laws,* $^\dagger$ starting with$$¬((¬P ∨ Q) ∨ (¬R ∨ ¬Q))$$ we first get $$\lnot (\lnot P\lor Q) \land \lnot (\lnot R \lor \lnot Q)$$

Then, using DeMorgan's laws, again, twice, we get $$(P \land \lnot Q) \land (R \land Q)$$

And you are correct, that gives us $$P\land \lnot Q \land R \land Q$$ (The second of the two options you though might be correct), which gives us $$P \land R \land (\lnot Q \land Q) \equiv P \land R \land False \equiv False.$$

---

$\dagger$ DeMorgan's laws:  $\lnot (a \lor b) \equiv (\lnot a \land \lnot b)$, and $\lnot (a\land b) \equiv (\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$.

Comment: Fail or False? $~~~$

Comment: False, because the task is reducing a proposition, which evaluates to false.  I use equivalence only to show from start to finish, the propositions are logically equivalent to False.

Comment: Yea! I see. Sorry...

Comment: Thanks for asking! No need for "sorry!"